# Does the sum from $1$ to infinity of $1/n^{1.01 }$ converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence

I looked this up on Wolfram Alpha and it said it converged to $100.578$. Is this correct? Much more importantly, how would I solve the question please? I am at pre-uni level (this is an old interview question) so I'm afraid even basic techniques from first-year analysis aren't allowed, I think.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, the sum converges to that value, and it is known that it converges for any $t>1$ (that is, $t=1.01$ in this case).  The value is given by the zeta function, which is famous, but somebody else here may tell you more, because I know almost nothing about it, not even how to calculate it.

Comment: You claim this is an interview question; where did you get the interview question? I would say if you aren't allowed to use things you know (e.g., either of the answers below), then the rules need to be spelled out more clearly.

Comment: A website claiming to have a list of past oxbridge interview questions - it seemed interesting so I tried it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on where in the world you are as to what pre-university allows.

In the UK you might reasonably argue that $$\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^{1.01}}dx \lt \sum_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^{1.01}} \lt 1+\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^{1.01}}dx$$ with a sketch to justify it.

[image]

The points you could make in the interview include:

- The left hand side is then $100$ and the right $101$, setting bounds on the sum.
- Careful examination of the sketch might take you to the sum being close to $100.5$
- A convexity argument would take this to slightly more than $100.5$.
- Some of the "slightly more" comes in the early terms which you might be able to calculate explicitly.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is standard consequence of p-series test: The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for $p>1$ and diverges for $p\leq1$. The convergence can be proved by [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) and by using convergence of geometric series.